# Alphabetical order, Array.Sort() doesn't work well

Tags: c#, .net

I have problem with alphabetical order. Array.Sort() doesn't work well in my case.

```
string str = "AaBbCc";
char[] arr = second.ToCharArray();
Array.Sort(arr);

// Output: ABCabc
// I need: AaBbCc
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you convert the string to a `char` array, you're essentially comparing using the ASCII indexes, and upper and lower case letters have different indexes.

Comment: But do you have any idea how to order it?

Comment: `str` already matches the needed output. Why are you doing anything to it at all (i.e. please use a better input sample - it's not clear if you always want the capital letter to appear before it's lowercase counterpart)?

Comment: From what I understand, the OP wants to first sort by letters in the alphabet first, so all `A`s, whether simple or capital, must come frist, then `B`s etc. Within each group, all capitals must come first.

Comment: @Sach Yeah, I'm sure you're correct, but it would be clearer if the sample input contained a lower case character that preceeded it's uppercase counterpart. As it is, the input is identical to the expected output, so it's not defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve what you're looking for with LINQ.

First, we need to break your characters up into a sequence of single character strings. We can do that with select.

```
str.Select(x => x.ToString())
```

Okay, now we want to order this list. The default sort for strings is word sort, which would order it like `aAbBcC`. Since you want to get the capitals first, we'll use the `OrdinalIgnoreCase` comparer, which will group our characters up.

```
   .OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Okay, so we've now grouped our characters. We'll now want to sort those groups ordinally to get the capitals to come first, using ThenBy.

```
   .ThenBy(x => x, StringComparer.Ordinal)
```

Finally, we can turn it into an array.

```
   .ToArray();
```

Bringing it together, we get the following:

```
var res = str.Select(x => x.ToString())
             .OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
             .ThenBy(x => x, StringComparer.Ordinal)
             .ToArray();
```

Which gives us an array that looks like this: `["A","a","B","b","C","c"]`

At this point, as @dvo has pointed out, we can turn it back into a single string with a call to String.Join, like so:

```
var resStr = string.Join("", res);
```

As @RufusL points out, we can do more for this query. Since we know we ultimately want a string, we can skip the `ToArray` call entirely and stick with the `IOrderedEnumerable<string>`.

```
var res = str.Select(x => x.ToString())
             .OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
             .ThenBy(x => x, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Since we aren't joining anything with strings we can use `string.Concat` instead of `string.Join`.

```
var resStr = string.Concat(res);
```

Comment: Good answer! I think it's also worth noting you can use this and get the result as a string by joining the array back together with no separator: `string.Join("", res)`. I'm guessing this is the OP's next step

Comment: This doesn't give me the answer as you states it does?

Comment: Sweet, this is beautiful now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code is ordering by the ASCII value, which is `65-90` for uppercase (`A-Z`) and `97-122` for lowercase (`a-z`).

Asuming you always want the uppercase letters to come before their lowercase counterparts, we can use a little trick to sort the lowercase letters just after their uppercase value by subtracting `31.5` from the ASCII value before doing the comparison.

By doing this, `a` becomes `65.5` (`97 - 31.5`) and will be sorted between `A` (`65`) and `B` (`66`). Likewise for all the other lower-case letters. This avoids the cost of creating a bunch of new strings for comparison and doing multiple orderings.

For example:

```
string str = "zZYyabCABcxX";
string ordered = string.Concat(str.OrderBy(c => c > 96 && c < 123 ? c - 31.5 : c));
Console.WriteLine(ordered);
```

We can also use `char.IsUpper` and `char.ToLower` instead of hard-coded ascii values:

```
// If the character is lower-case, use the value of its upper-case counterpart plus .5
ordered = string.Concat(str.OrderBy(c => char.IsLower(c) ? char.ToUpper(c) + .5 : c));
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Edit**

To answer one of the comments, if you want to use this same method to sort the characters such that the lower-case letters come *before* their upper-case counterparts, you would then subtract `32.5` if the character is in the upper-case range. This way an `a` (`97`) becomes `64.5` (`97 - 32.5`) and will be sorted before `A` (`65`):

```
string ordered = string.Concat(str.OrderBy(c => c > 96 && c < 123 ? c - 32.5 : c));
```

Or using the trick with `char.IsLower` and `char.ToUpper` instead of hard-coded ascii values:

```
// If the character is lower-case, use the value of its upper-case counterpart minus .5
ordered = string.Concat(str.OrderBy(c => char.IsLower(c) ? char.ToUpper(c) - .5 : c));
```

Comment: How this line will look like if we want the same trick ,but lowerCase letters always to be before uppercase?

string ordered = string.Concat(str.OrderBy(c => c > 96 && c < 122 ? c - 31.5 : c));

How this part will looks like c - 31.5?

Example: AaVv576 - > aAvV567

Comment: In that case you would subtract `32.5`, so that the upper-case value would come just *before* the lower-case value instead of just after it. I updated the answer with some samples.

Comment: You'd have to do additional comparisons if you want to put numbers after letters, but it's the same idea - add the difference between `z` and `0` to the ascii value: `char.IsNumber(c) ? c + 'z' - '0'`

Comment: Another question pops up regarding ordering/sorting. If we have to reverse some string for example "Love" - > "Evol" ,how we keep the first letter with uppercase for E if L was uppercase at first?

Comment: You can use `char.IsUpper` to determine if a character is upper or lower case, and `char.ToUpper` to force a character to uppercase. I already updated the question with examples for that. Reversing a string is a different question than sorting, however.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a solution that doesn't require doing math with the ASCII values: we can first order the characters so that the upper and lower case of each character are next to each other by using `OrderBy(char.ToLower)` (which sorts by the ASCII value of the character in lower case), and then we can sort them by `char.IsLower`, which will then sort the lower case characters after the upper case characters:

```
string str = "zZYyabCABcxX";
string ordered = string.Concat(str.OrderBy(char.ToLower).ThenBy(char.IsLower));

// ordered == "AaBbCcXxYyZz"
```